# A question about generalized Fibonacci sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can the following lemma be proved?

Lemma (Rokach-Goldstein)

Let $x_i$ be  a finite generalized Fibonacci sequence of positive integer numbers,  $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m$ such that for every $2\le i\le m$, we have $x_i=x_{i-1}+x_{i-2}$, and where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are coprime to each other.

In this case, there exists some $n$, $0\le n\le m$, such that $x_n$ is coprime to the sum of all numbers in the sequence.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind when you say "the sum of all [the] numbers in the sequence"?

Comment: Further, supposing you have a sensible way to define "the sum of all [the] numbers in the sequence" you can take x=1, can't you?

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you, but you should learn some very basic TeX so that you can make your posts more readable. As Jose indicated, it's not clear what you're asking. Maybe you want $x_n$ to be coprime to the sum of the previous terms $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}$. Finally, when you say "can it be proved", you shouldn't call it a lemma with your name attached. Do you know how to prove it? If not, ask it as a question. If so, say so, and then what are you asking?

Comment: We have $x_n=x_1F_n+x_0F_{n-1}$. From there you can derive an explicit formula for $x_0+\dots+x_{n-1}$ and compare it to $x_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the editing. The question referrs to a finite sequence. It seems that there must be at least one number in it thst is co prime to the sum of all numbers in the finite sequence. I dont know how to prove it nut it seems true.

Comment: see the following example : 2,7,9,16,25. the sum is 59. the number 7 is co prime to it.

Comment: I made a few edits to clarify that we're talking about a finite sequence. Please check that I didn't change the meaning of the question. "it seems true" What makes you say that, Arie? Have you tried it for all $x_0,x_1,m$ up to $1,000,000$?

Comment: Here's an almost-counterexample: $x_0=18$, $x_1=187$, $m=8$. The sequence goes $18,187,205,392,597,989,1586,2575,4161$, the sum is $10710$, and just one of the nine terms, $989$, is relatively prime to the sum.

Comment: Gerry ,  thanks  a lot for your example ! very nice ! to your question , yes - i tried it for a million cases , with very large numbers , and various lengths of lists , and it did not fail.

Comment: Gerry, thanks a lot. you gave an excellent example that shows that the lemma is not correct. i wonder if there might be such an example if the sum is odd.

Answer (score 9):

$x_0=1874587$, $x_1=89$. $\gcd(x_0,x_1)=1$. Let $m=10$. $\sum_0^{10}x_i=166850970=2\times3\times5\times11\times13\times19\times23\times89$.

$x_0=1874587\equiv0\bmod11$.

$x_1=89\equiv0\bmod89$.

$x_2=x_1+x_0=1874676\equiv0\bmod2$.

$x_3=x_2+x_1=1874765\equiv0\bmod5$.

$x_4=x_3+x_2=3749441\equiv0\bmod19$.

$x_5=x_4+x_3=5624206\equiv0\bmod2$.

$x_6=x_5+x_4=9373647\equiv0\bmod3$.

$x_7=x_6+x_5=14997853\equiv0\bmod13$.

$x_8=x_7+x_6=24371500\equiv0\bmod2$.

$x_9=x_8+x_7=39369353\equiv0\bmod23$.

$x_{10}=x_9+x_8=63740853\equiv0\bmod11$.

It may be worth checking my arithmetic.